# exiting out Tcl_DoOneEvent function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads, tcl

I have TCL files which are sourced  in the C++ files. 
for which i have used Tcl_DoOneEvent function in the end to take care of all the TCL calls.
i also have a few threads called in the Main function. in order to exit from all threads and function i have a quit function written. so in the current case i see that all the pthreads and other Function are terminated except the Tcl_DoOneEvent function called in the end. which is giving out an segmentation error. 
is there a way to exit out out the while(1) function from other function.

```
main()
{
...
...
pthread_create(thread1);
pthread_create(thread2);
while(1) Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL_EVENTS);
return(0);
}

quit_fn()
{
...
...
pthread_cancel(thread1);
pthread_cancel(thread2);
...
// exit(0) ; ->  this also results in segmentation error 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to exit the while loop, you should change the condition of the loop and make it depend on a variable that you can change from another thread (declare it as volatile).

```
volatile bool exitLoop = false;

while (!exitLoop) 
{
    Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL_EVENTS);
}
```

I'm not sure, but this might get indefinitely blocked if there aren't any more events. Two possible solutions might be using the TCL_DONT_WAIT flag:

```
Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL_EVENTS | TCL_DONT_WAIT);
// sleep some time here in order to avoid busy wait
```

Or better, trigger an event from your quit function so that Tcl_DoOneEvent wakes up, and in the next iteration your exitLoop variable is true.

Finally, I'd recommend that you follow the same loop and exit condition approach for all your threads. Instead of using pthread_cancel to finish a thread, try using pthread_join. That way you control exactly at which point the thread exits and you can do some cleanup and avoid segmentation faults or other kinds of error.

Comment: Having the quit function send an event to the main thread is the recommended approach. The event can have a trivial handler, or the event handler can be what sets `exitLoop`, which then doesn't need to be `volatile` as it is only accessed from one thread. `TCL_DONT_WAIT` isn't recommended for this use case; Tcl sleeps for events efficiently without it.

Comment: I agree with that, sending an event and letting Tcl handle the sleep is better. volatile is not needed, provided that the flag is never used from the other threads (but we don't know if that's the case from the code).